# Accessing json key, value with python by key not index

Tags: python, json

I have the JSON file shown below. I'm very new to programming and after a lot of trial and error I was able to access individual key,values by index in the file as in the code shown below. I want to be able to search by key through multiple objects. For example I would like to search by key "vedette" and return "academie Française", "Quai conti", "Institut", "Les quarante". Any advice on how to do that would be great.

```
with open('DESformatted.json') as data_file:    
    d = json.load(data_file)
pprint (d['DES'][0]['vedette'])

[u'Acad\xe9mie fran\xe7aise']

{
    "DES": [
        {
            "vedette": ["Académie française"],
            "synonymes": [
                "Institut",
                "Quai Conti",
                "les Quarante"
            ],
            "liste10": [
                "Institut",
                "66",
                "Quai Conti",
                "66",
                "les Quarante",
                "66"
            ],
            "cliques": [
                [
                    "Académie française",
                    "Institut"
                ],
                [
                    "Académie française",
                    "Quai Conti"
                ],
                [
                    "Académie française",
                    "les Quarante"
                ]
            ]
        },
        {
            "vedette": ["Quai Conti"],
            "synonymes": [
                "Académie française"
            ],
            "liste10": [
                "Académie française",
                "200"
            ],
            "cliques": [
                [
                    "Académie française",
                    "Quai Conti"
                ]
            ]
        },
        {
            "vedette": ["les Quarante"],
            "synonymes": [
                "Académie française"
            ],
            "liste10": [
                "Académie française",
                "200"
            ],
            "cliques": [
                [
                    "Académie française",
                    "les Quarante"
                ]
            ]
        },
        {
            "vedette": ["Institut"],
            "synonymes": [
                "Académie française",
                "académie"
            ],
            "liste10": [
                "Académie française",
                "100",
                "académie",
                "100"
            ],
            "cliques": [
                [
                    "Académie française",
                    "Institut"
                ],
                [
                    "Institut",
                    "académie"
                ]
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: "*I'm very new to programming*" -- May I suggest that you pause whatever you are working on and read  [The Python Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/index.html)? Spending the time now will save you both time and frustration later.

Answer (score 0):

The value associated with `"DES"` is a list of objects, so you can iterate though them like this:

```
for obj in d["DES"]:
    print(obj["vedette"])
```

Output:

```
['Acad\xe9mie fran\xe7aise']
['Quai Conti']
['les Quarante']
['Institut']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like:

```
>>> vedettes = []

>>> for x in d['DES']:
    vedettes += x['vedette']

>>> vedettes
['Acad\xc3\xa9mie fran\xc3\xa7aise', 'Quai Conti', 'les Quarante', 'Institut']
```

Here i am iterating over all the values in `DES` key of dictionary `d`. Then i am storing value of `vedette` obtained from each iteration into a `vedettes` list. This is done by adding the `vedette` list obtained and the `vedettes` list so that all the elements of the `vedette` list obtained in each step gets added in final `vedettes` list.

`vedettes` list contains your desired output then.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to the correct `for` loops that others present, you can use [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).

```
>>> import json
>>> d = json.load(open('DESformatted.json'))
>>> [x['vedette'] for x in d['DES']]
[[u'Acad\xe9mie fran\xe7aise'], [u'Quai Conti'], [u'les Quarante'], [u'Institut']]
>>>
```